# Starting a WebAppContext in isolation

Tags: java, scala, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to start a Jetty server with a web context. The `web.xml` that I am passing contains a custom class that is (for different reasons) on the classpath of the code executing the code below. I expect Jetty not to be able to find the class that is specified in the `web.xml`, but it does.

How would I construct a `new Server` with `WebAppContext` that will **not** load classes from the current context?

The code below is in Scala, but it should give you an idea what I have tried. If you answer with Java that is perfectly fine.

```
// A reference to the root class loader, this one should not know 
// about any of my custom classes
val rootLoader = {
  // Recursive method to find the loader without parent
  def parent(loader:ClassLoader):ClassLoader = {
    val p = loader.getParent
    if (p == null) loader else parent(p)
  }
  parent(getClass.getClassLoader)
}

// Check if the custom ClassFile is available from the rootLoader
val className = classOf[my.custom.servlet.ClassFile].getName
val classAvailable =
  try {
    rootLoader.loadClass(className)
    true
  } catch {
    case e:ClassNotFoundException => false
  }
// If I'm not insane no error is thrown
if (classAvailable) sys.error("Class should not be available")

// Create a WebAppContext using an empty WebAppClassLoader 
// based on that rootLoader
val context = new WebAppContext()
context.setParentLoaderPriority(false)
//context.setClassLoader(new WebAppClassLoader(rootLoader, context))
context.setClassLoader(rootLoader)
context.setContextPath("/")
context.setDescriptor(webXmlFile)
context.setResourceBase(resourceBase)

// Create an start the server with the context
val server = new Server(port)
server.setHandler(context)
server.start()
```

I expected the context **not** to find the class in question.

Comment: Question is unclear.  Seems like you wanting to have a server class override a webapp class?  Is that the right?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt The end result is me wanting the `WebAppContext` to load a class that is (as a string) in the `web.xml` using the class loader. The class (another version) however is also present in the code creating the server. The above code shows that the `WebAppContext` seems to not respect the classloader: it finds the class. This is a simplified example showing that the `WebAppContext` is reaching to another classloader trying to find the class. I wonder what I am doing wrong, I expect it not to be able to find that class.

Comment: the example you have is overly contrived, i can see you are attempting to manipulate the classloaders, but there is bound to be a better way, but first we need to understand what your goal is, not your attempts at getting there.  So its a class, defined in the web.xml of the webapp, and you want that class to load from the server classloader (your special case need), not the webapp classloader (which has the same class, by name, but not functionality).  Is that a correct statement of your question?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Almost, I want it to load the the class using the webapp classloader, but it loads the class using the server classloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK EEColor, I've had a dig around in the code and I think we have 2 issues for which I've opened these bugs:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=447462
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=447461

Now, bug #1 is the reason why even if you set a completely isolated classloader the webapp is magically able to still load the class. Bug #2 shouldn't really affect you, unless you start to play around with Joakim's suggestion of setting system and server classes, and even then you're probably ok, because the class exists in both the container classloader parent hierarchy and the webapp classloader and the bug only occurs when a system class is missing from the container classloader but present in the webapp classloader.

So, you can try using Joakim's suggestion of adding the class as a system class and that should work. Alternatively, you should also be able to simply set WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true) and that will also try the container classloader hierarchy first. Although be aware that setParentPriority(true) will apply to all classloading for the webapp, whilst Joakim's suggestion limits the different loading behaviour to just the class in question.

Jan

Comment: This might be why I am observing what I'm observing. The problem I am having might be in a different part... Debugging by trying to minimalize it probably brought me to these bugs

Comment: This may be the cause of one of the problems I am experiencing at work. We have a webapp loaded that uses a slf4j-binding and also outside the webappcontext we have a slf4j-binding. We are getting a `LinkageError` regarding `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;` because both classloaders have a different version. That should not matter with rela isolation. Thanks for reporting the bug.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not well stated, its hard to understand what your *goal* is.

*Tip: In the future, ask how to reach a goal, then state the path you attempted*

Lets assume you have a webapp called `example-webapp.war`

It has a simple `WEB-INF/web.xml` with a servlet entry as such ...

```xml
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.foo.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The `example-webapp.war` comes with its own `com.company.foo.TestServlet` (found in the webapp's `WEB-INF/classes` directory)

Now, you have a embedded-jetty instance, you want to launch `example-webapp.war`, but you want to use an implementation of `com.company.foo.TestServlet` that exists outside of the `example-webapp.war` (with different functionality).

You can accomplish this by first recognizing that the servlet spec has classloader isolation of a webapp from its server, and then configuring that classloader isolation layer to poke a small hole through this isolation.

This hole needs to:

1. Make the webapp classloader capable of seeing the server class
2. Force the webapp to use the server class version over the webapp class version

This is easy enough to accomplish in embedded-jetty.

Lets start with making a custom version of `com.company.foo.TestServlet` and making it available in the classpath for the embedded-jetty server.

Finally, configure your `WebAppContext` to configure the classloader isolation hole mentioned above.  (Using the system classes and server classes configurations)

```java
package demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class EmbedWithOverridenServlet
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int port = 8080;
        Server server = new Server(port);

        String wardir = "path/to/example-webapp.war";

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setWar(wardir);
        webapp.setContextPath("/");

        // don't hide server classes from webapps (hole #1 from answer)
        // (allow webapp to use ones from system classloader)
        webapp.addServerClass("-com.company.foo.");

        // webapp cannot change or replace these classes
        // force use of server classes (hole #2 from answer)
        webapp.addSystemClass("com.company.foo.");

        server.setHandler(webapp);

        try
        {
            server.start();
            server.dumpStdErr();
            makeWebRequest(new URI("http://localhost:8080/test"));
        }
        finally
        {
            server.stop();
        }
    }

    private static void makeWebRequest(URI uri) throws IOException
    {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)uri.toURL().openConnection();
        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.printf("Response Status: %d%n", status);

        if(status != 200)
        {
            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s%n", conn.getResponseMessage());
            return;
        }

        try(InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(reader))
        {
            System.out.printf("Response Content Type: %s%n", conn.getHeaderField("Content-Type"));
            String line;
            while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.printf("[resp] %s%n",line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: 2014-Oct-16**

A project demonstrating this is available at [github.com/jetty-project/jetty-classloader-manipulation](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-classloader-manipulation)

The `example-webapp` is a pretty normal webapp with a [single servlet](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-classloader-manipulation/blob/master/example-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) of [its own](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-classloader-manipulation/blob/master/example-webapp/src/main/java/com/company/foo/TestServlet.java).

The `example-embedded-servlet-override` has a [replacement for that servlet](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-classloader-manipulation/blob/master/example-embedded-servlet-override/src/main/java/com/company/foo/TestServlet.java), along with the [embedded jetty main class](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-classloader-manipulation/blob/master/example-embedded-servlet-override/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EmbedWithOverridenServlet.java) to deploy the `example-webapp`.  It has a [system property check against `use.server.class`](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-classloader-manipulation/blob/5e3b591131d6ecab2403c09c807871483a5ef86e/example-embedded-servlet-override/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EmbedWithOverridenServlet.java#L26) to demonstrate both behaviors, normal (isolated), and overridden (hole punch).

The output looks like this:

*Normal/Isolated Behavior: (no system prop. or using `-Duse.server.class=false`)*

```
Response Status: 200
Response Content Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
[resp] Hello Test Class: com.company.foo.TestServlet 
       from ClassLoader WebAppClassLoader=2113433461@7df86f75
```

*Overridden/Hole Punch Behavior: (using `-Duse.server.class=true`)*

```
Response Status: 200
Response Content Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
[resp] <html><body>
[resp] <h1>Hello Server Impl</h1>
[resp] <p>Class: com.company.foo.TestServlet 
       from ClassLoader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e68a2b</p>
[resp] </body></html>
```

Hope this helps you understand the nature of what you are working with.

Comment: Joakim, you can also make the pattern specific to a class, so do webapp.addSystemClass("com.company.foo.TestServlet").
Jan

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Maybe Jetty is behaving as expected, I will try to create a positive testcase in light of the bugs @Jan revealed. My observed behavior was that it loaded a class from the server instead of the webapp. It might be caused by the fact that it could not find the class in the webapp.

Comment: @EECOLOR i went ahead and made a testable project for you.  When you are working on your positive testcase, the first thing you need to do is eliminate all of the `setClassLoader()` efforts and just work with the standard behavior, don't immediately jump into thinking that managing classloader hierarchies is required (it rarely is).

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt First of all: thank you for helping me and providing an example like this. In my case I actually need to use a classloader because I am working on an sbt plugin. The positive test case actually worked out, here are the changes required to load from a jar using your example code: [jetty-classloader-manipulation](https://github.com/EECOLOR/jetty-classloader-manipulation/pull/1/files). Note that I did not use maven, but sbt, you can ignore those files. I will now go back to my actual code to find the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that the class in question resides in WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes.  No idea why you'd want to ensure that the webapp can't find this class, but try using a classloader that isn't an instance of WebAppClassLoader, like a new URLClassLoader with an empty list of urls and the rootLoader as its parent.

Jan

Comment: I want it to not find the class because the class is part of a package that the code executing `server.start` relies on. The problem is that Jetty finds a class it should not find from a security perspective.

Comment: Even with an empty URLClassLoader it manages to find the class. It seems the `WebAppContext` is not using the given classloader to load the servlet in the descriptor.

Comment: OK EEColor, I've dug around and I think we have 2 issues for which I've opened these bugs: 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=447462   and    
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=447461

In your case, if I understand correctly, there are 2 different versions of the same class: one on the container classpath and one on the webapp classpath, and you want to use the one from the container.  If so, then just use WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true) and that should find the class that is on the container's classpath.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was actually the other way around. I managed to get the positive test working thanks to the feedback of @JoakimErdfelt. I added a link to the comment of his answer. I was thrown off by the first bug while debugging my code.